# Scan wireless network for devices and their mac address on android 10+

Tags: android, networking, ip, mac-address

I'm trying to implement a network scanner (like fing) to scan the wireless network and find all devices that are connected. The main issue here is reading their MAC address, since after android 10 you cannot access the ARP table on device. My question is that how apps like fing are working just fine? Can protocols like UPNP solve the problem somehow? Or is there another way that I couldn't find?

Note: the best working answer that I found was to use "ip neighbor" command, and that only works if your target sdk is 29 and below, go above and you get a permission exception.

Comment: I have exactly the same question. How could App like Net Analyzer just work fine? Is it a tech hack or a business trade with google？

Comment: @Rangtian You have to use the NDK to implement this. Check out the discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/aaronjwood/PortAuthority/issues/134) on github.